# Encoding when serializing form

Tags: javascript, html, serialization, encoding

when i insert regular english characters in input and then serialize form (form.serialize), it's all right. But when i enter Georgian characters (ასდფ), i have encoding problems, it shows something like this:

```
%E1%83%A1%E1%83%90%E1%83%93%E1%83%A4%E1%83%90%E1%83%A1%E1%83%93%E1%83%A4.
```

Thanks for help in advance

EDIT:

THE QUESTION IS!!! --> How can i serialize form without encoding it's values?

Comment: The `.serialize()` URL-encodes the form values for submission, what is your question?

Comment: Please post code how to use it

Comment: I want to decode it on server side or don't allow .serialize to encode values

Comment: I have model binding in asp.net mvc, so encoded values are stored in model

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know it'n not the best solution, but i did this:

```
function stringify(array) {
    var result = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (i != 0)
            result += '&';
        result += array[i].name + '=' + array[i].value;
    }
    return result;
}

stringify(form.serializeArray())
```

Now characters are not encoded

Comment: Very simple and this works perfectly. +1